# String immutable?

Tags: java, string, immutability, heap-memory, stack-memory

Can anyone answer me please?

```
public class ReplaceString{

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String a = "Hariom";
        a = a.replace('H', 'b');
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: It _is_ immutable; when you .replace() you create a new string object. Don't be mixing with immutable objects and object references

Comment: You made `a` refer to a different String. The old String still contains Hariom, but now you have a new one as well, which contains bariom, and you made a point to bariom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `String` is immutable, which means you cannot change the string value on the same address. If you change it, it will create a new object and you have to assign it to the current string object. For example,

```
 String a = "Hariom";
 a.replace('H', 'b');
 System.out.println(a);   //will print "Hariom"
```

because `a` is not changed. Instead, you created a new `String` in memory with the value `bariom` and to show that change to `a`, you have to point the newly created string to `a`, i.e.

```
a= a.replace('H', 'b');
```

Maybe this would be a bit more clear:

**Step 1**: `String a = "Hariom";` you create a new string in memory and the variable `a` points to it.

---

[image]

---

**Step 2**: `a.replace('H', 'b');` if you replace some character in `String` `a`, a new `String` is created in the heap with no variable pointing to it.

---

[image]

---

**Step 3**:  `a= a.replace('H', 'b');` if you call `replace()` and assign it to the variable `a`, what happens is that the new `String` `bariom` is created in the heap. Then you assign it to `a` causing `a` to point to the new `String`.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 6):

change your code to :

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String a = "Hariom";
        String b = a.replace('H', 'b'); // returns a new string instance
        System.out.println(a==b); // prints false
    }
```

`b` and `a` are *different* objects. `immutable` means you cannot *modify* that object.

Note : *Reflection* can be used to break *immutability* of Strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = a.replace('H', 'b');
```

This doesn't modify the `String` `a`, it returns a new `String` instance (unless there is nothing to replace, in which case the original `String` is returned).

Comment: Ok what about old String Hariom? how to get it ? And when this will garbage collected?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi In this code snippet, there's no reference left to the original String, which means it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

**According to Javadocs:**

> [`String#replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar

```
String a = "Hariom";
a = a.replace('H', 'b');
/* method returns new instance of String ("bariom")
   and you referencing the new instance to variable a, 
   so now String object "Hariom" is no longer referenced by any variable
   and is available for garbage collection.
*/
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The row

```
a.replace('H', 'b');
```

generate a **new String**.  Then you set the a variable to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

`a.replace` does not modify `a`, it returns a *new* String object. If you call `a.replace` without reassigning to `a`, you will notice that the original String has not changed.

Variables can contain immutable objects, but you are still able to reassign to them. Reassigning does not change the object, it only changes *which* object the variable refers to.